# Express.js - Posted data not rendering until refresh the page

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js, handlebars.js

I am send and fetch data from `MySql Database` with `Express.js` and `Sequelize.js`. All my code works correctly. My problem is, posted data not rendering on the `Handlebars` template until refresh the page. I also tried `res.render` method after `SaveSettings` method but don't worked. I want to render updated data after redirect.

### Solved

*You're missing `return` before `settings.update()`. Without it, the `SaveSettings` promise resolves before the update has completed - **@Phil***

```
function SaveSettings(Model, values) {
  return Model.findByPk(1).then((settings) => {
    if (!settings) {
      return Model.create(values).catch((e) => console.log(e));
    } else {
      return settings.update(values).catch((e) => console.log(e));
    }
  });
}
```

### Routes

```
router.get("/admin", csrf, isAuth, controller.getGeneral);
router.post("/admin", isAuth, controller.postGeneral);
```

### Controllers

```
exports.getGeneral = (req, res) => {
  Models.General.findByPk(1).then((result) => {
    return res.render("dashboard/index", {
      title: "General Settings",
      data: result,
    });
  });
};

exports.postGeneral = (req, res) => {
  SaveSettings(Models.General, req.body)
  .then(() => res.redirect("/admin"));
};
```

### SaveSettings Method

```
function SaveSettings(Model, values) {
  return Model.findByPk(1).then((settings) => {
    if (!settings) {
      return Model.create(values).catch((e) => console.log(e));
    } else {
      settings.update(values).catch((e) => console.log(e));
    }
  });
}
```

### Frontend

```
<form action="" method="post" class="table-responsive">
  <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="{{csrfToken}}" />
  <div class="d-flex justify-content-end">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
  </div>
  <table class="table table-striped table-sm mt-3">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">Slot</th>
        <th scope="col">Value</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="align-middle">Name</td>
        <td class="align-middle">
          <input
            name="name"
            class="form-control"
            type="text"
            value="{{data.name}}"
          />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="align-middle">Description</td>
        <td class="align-middle">
          <input
            name="description"
            class="form-control"
            type="text"
            value="{{data.description}}"
          />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="align-middle">Email</td>
        <td class="align-middle">
          <input
            name="email_address"
            class="form-control"
            type="email"
            value="{{data.email_address}}"
          />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: How is the POST being generated from the browser?  Please show the code/HTML that originates the POST.

Comment: You need to program some JavaScript to react upon the response given back by server to change elements/etc.

Comment: @jfriend00 I added the Frontend Code.

Comment: @BGPHiJACK Thanks for the comment, I was wondering how can I manage this issue on the server side.

Comment: @BGPHiJACK _"program some JavaScript to react upon the response"_... no they don't. Their server-side code redirects to `GET /admin` after saving the data. OP isn't using AJAX

Comment: What does `SaveSettings` do? I suspect it's resolving the promise before data is actually persisted

Comment: @Phil I added it.

Comment: You're missing `return` before `settings.update()`. Without it, the `SaveSettings` promise resolves before the update has completed

Comment: @Phil Thank you very much, i don't saw it. Working fine now.